# Open subsets of the n-torus containing no nontrivial loops

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, torus

Let $T^n$ denote the $n$-dimensional torus. Suppose there is an open subset $U\subset T^n$ not containing any nontrivial loop. Does this imply that the inclusion $U\hookrightarrow T^n$ is nullhomotopic?

Comment: By "nontrivial loops" do you mean not nullhomotopic?

Comment: If the pushforward homomorphism $\pi_1(U,x_0)\to \pi_1(T^n,x_0)$ is a constant homomorphism, then there is a lifting of $U$ to the universal cover of $T^n$.  Since the universal cover admits a deformation retract to each of its singleton subsets, that lifting is nullhomotopic.

Comment: @ArunDebray Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for that comment. Somehow, I missed this reasoning as I was distracted by the fact that U might not be path connected.

Comment: I was also assuming that $U$ is  path connected.  However, you can repeat the argument with any connected component of $U$.

Comment: @JasonStarr You're absolutely right as $T^n$ is path connected. Thank you.